# Expandable listview notifydatasetchanged() not working in asynchtask

Tags: android

My activity consists of an ExpandableListView and the and couple of buttons and a textview at the bottom like in the image below.

[image]

When the page loads, listview is filled based on the date from the TextView. It is working fine. When I click the Next or previous button it should update the listview based on the next or previous date, but I dont where to call the notifydatasetchanged or how to. I'm calling the same AsynchTask both on page create and on button clicks with date as the parameter. When I click any of the buttons, app crashes. I saw other similar topics, but couldn't find a solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Regards.

```
public class GetPatientVitalsTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    public VitalListActivity vitalsActivity;
    private Activity activity;
    private Context context;
    private View rootView;
    private GogchProgressDialog progressDialog;

    public GetPatientVitalsTask(VitalListActivity activity, View rootView){
        super();
        this.activity = activity;
        this.rootView = rootView;
        this.context = this.activity.getApplicationContext();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = new GogchProgressDialog(activity, R.drawable.gogch_progress_spinner);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String sDate = params[0];
        String message = null;
        String url = "http://test.gogch.com/gch-restful/vitals/calender?date=" + sDate;
        HttpClient httpClient = ServiceHelper.getHttpClient();
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();

        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            message = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            Log.d("Http Post Response:", message);
        }
        catch(ClientProtocolException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return message;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String responseText) {
        ExpandableListView expListView = (ExpandableListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.vitalsListView);
        final List<Vitals> vitalsList = VitalService.buildVitalsList(responseText);

        VitalListAdapter vitalAdapter = null;
        vitalAdapter = new VitalListAdapter(activity, vitalsList);
        expListView.setAdapter(vitalAdapter);
        vitalAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Logcat

```
04-28 15:09:22.627    4654-4654/com.cinch.gogch E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.cinch.gogch, PID: 4654
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ExpandableListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ExpandableListAdapter)' on a null object reference
            at com.cinch.gogch.tasks.GetPatientVitalsTask.onPostExecute(GetPatientVitalsTask.java:89)
            at com.cinch.gogch.tasks.GetPatientVitalsTask.onPostExecute(GetPatientVitalsTask.java:36)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:636)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:177)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:653)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: check expListView ...

Comment: sorry. I dont understand, check expListView for what? can you explain?

Comment: check if this R.id.vitalsListView is the correct id of your expandable listview

Comment: It's correct. I did mention in my question, listview get filled for the first time when page is loaded and app crashes only when buttons are clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use to declare in your Activty:
final ExpandableListView expListView = (ExpandableListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.vitalsListView);

and use the expListView in Asynctask for setting  the adapter

Comment: Thank you, it works. But we don't need to declare it final, declaring as final made my app crash, giving error "    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.cinch.gogch/com.cinch.gogch.activities.VitalListActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference". I created an instance of ExpandableListView in my activity and passed it to the AsynchTask by constructor.